# dsPIC primary oscillator works for a few seconds or clock doesn't switch

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, oscillator

I'm using a dsPIC33EP512MC806 and can't get the primary oscillator to work. The internal works fine, but if I switch to the primary it either hangs on Clock switch or goes in to the `_OscillatorFail` trap. Sometimes it seems like it works with the primay, but after a few seconds it just stops.

The used oscillator is a [10MHz 12pF](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/txc-corporation/AB-10.000MALE-T/887-1699-1-ND/3459408)

Code used for testing:

```c
//** CONFIG BITS **//
// FGS
#pragma config GWRP = OFF               // General Segment Write-Protect bit (General Segment may be written)
#pragma config GSS = OFF                // General Segment Code-Protect bit (General Segment Code protect is disabled)
#pragma config GSSK = OFF               // General Segment Key bits (General Segment Write Protection and Code Protection is Disabled)

// FOSCSEL
#pragma config FNOSC = FRC              // Initial Oscillator Source Selection bits (Internal Fast RC (FRC))
#pragma config IESO = ON               // Two-speed Oscillator Start-up Enable bit (Start up with user-selected oscillator source)

// FOSC
#pragma config POSCMD = HS              // Primary Oscillator Mode Select bits (HS Crystal Oscillator Mode)
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = OFF           // OSC2 Pin Function bit (OSC2 is clock output)
#pragma config IOL1WAY = OFF            // Peripheral pin select configuration (Allow multiple reconfigurations)
#pragma config FCKSM = CSECME           // Clock Switching Mode bits (Clock switching is enabled,Fail-safe Clock Monitor is disabled)

// FWDT
#pragma config WDTPOST = PS32768        // Watchdog Timer Postscaler bits (1:32,768)
#pragma config WDTPRE = PR128           // Watchdog Timer Prescaler bit (1:128)
#pragma config PLLKEN = ON              // PLL Lock Wait Enable bit (Clock switch to PLL source will wait until the PLL lock signal is valid.)
#pragma config WINDIS = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Window Enable bit (Watchdog Timer in Non-Window mode)
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (Watchdog timer enabled/disabled by user software)

// FPOR
#pragma config FPWRT = PWR128           // Power-on Reset Timer Value Select bits (128ms)
#pragma config BOREN = ON               // Brown-out Reset (BOR) Detection Enable bit (BOR is enabled)
#pragma config ALTI2C1 = OFF            // Alternate I2C pins for I2C1 (SDA1/SCK1 pins are selected as the I/O pins for I2C1)

// FICD
#pragma config ICS = PGD3               // ICD Communication Channel Select bits (Communicate on PGEC3 and PGED3)
#pragma config RSTPRI = PF              // Reset Target Vector Select bit (Device will obtain reset instruction from Primary flash)
#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF             // JTAG Enable bit (JTAG is disabled)

// FAS
#pragma config AWRP = OFF               // Auxiliary Segment Write-protect bit (Aux Flash may be written)
#pragma config APL = OFF                // Auxiliary Segment Code-protect bit (Aux Flash Code protect is disabled)
#pragma config APLK = OFF               // Auxiliary Segment Key bits (Aux Flash Write Protection and Code Protection is Disabled)
//** END OF CONFIG BITS **//

#define FCY 60000000

#include <stdint.h>
#include <libpic30.h>

#include <xc.h>

void __attribute__ ((interrupt, no_auto_psv)) _OscillatorFail(void)
{
    OSCCONbits.CF = 0;
    while(1);
}

int main(void) {

    // output
    TRISDbits.TRISD0 = 0;
    // turn led on before clock switch
    PORTDbits.RD0 = 1;

    // setup clock for 60 mips @ 10MHz
    CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST = 0;
    CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE = 0;
    PLLFBDbits.PLLDIV = 28;

    // Initiate Clock Switch to Primary Oscillator with PLL (NOSC=0b011)
    __builtin_write_OSCCONH(0b011);
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x01);

    // Wait for Clock switch to occur
    while (OSCCONbits.COSC != 0b011);
    // Wait for PLL to lock
    while (OSCCONbits.LOCK != 1);


    while (1) {
        PORTDbits.RD0 ^= 1;
        __delay_ms(100);
    }
}
```

Things already tried:

- Resoldering everything including the dsPIC
- Replaced all caps needed for it
- Replaced the oscillator and its caps
- Tried different caps for the Oscillator (12pF, 18pF, 33pF)
- Disabled watchdog

Not sure what to do at this point, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a problem with the watchdog? try to stop it.

Comment: `#pragma config WINDIS = OFF` should disable it, currently it's stuck in one of the while loops, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The PLL parameter you are setting:

```
    // setup clock for 60 mips @ 10MHz
    CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST = 0;
    CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE = 0;
    PLLFBDbits.PLLDIV = 28;
```

Does not setup the PLL for a 60 MIPS instruction clock.

Your settings result in a 37.5 MIPS instruction clock.

This code works for me please try it on your hardware:

```
/*
 * File:     main.c
 * Author:   dan1138
 * Target:   dsPIC33EP512MC806
 * Compiler: XC16 v1.36
 * IDE:      MPLABX v5.15
 *
 * Created on July 30, 2019, 3:08 PM
 */

// FGS
#pragma config GWRP = OFF               // General Segment Write-Protect bit (General Segment may be written)
#pragma config GSS = OFF                // General Segment Code-Protect bit (General Segment Code protect is disabled)
#pragma config GSSK = OFF               // General Segment Key bits (General Segment Write Protection and Code Protection is Disabled)

// FOSCSEL
#pragma config FNOSC = FRC              // Initial Oscillator Source Selection bits (Internal Fast RC (FRC))
#pragma config IESO = OFF               // Two-speed Oscillator Start-up Enable bit (Start up with user-selected oscillator source)

// FOSC
#pragma config POSCMD = HS              // Primary Oscillator Mode Select bits (HS Crystal Oscillator Mode)
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = OFF           // OSC2 Pin Function bit (OSC2 is clock output)
#pragma config IOL1WAY = OFF            // Peripheral pin select configuration (Allow multiple reconfigurations)
#pragma config FCKSM = CSECME           // Clock Switching Mode bits (Both Clock switching and Fail-safe Clock Monitor are enabled)

// FWDT
#pragma config WDTPOST = PS32768        // Watchdog Timer Postscaler bits (1:32,768)
#pragma config WDTPRE = PR128           // Watchdog Timer Prescaler bit (1:128)
#pragma config PLLKEN = ON              // PLL Lock Wait Enable bit (Clock switch to PLL source will wait until the PLL lock signal is valid.)
#pragma config WINDIS = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Window Enable bit (Watchdog Timer in Non-Window mode)
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (Watchdog timer enabled/disabled by user software)

// FPOR
#pragma config FPWRT = PWR128           // Power-on Reset Timer Value Select bits (128ms)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF              // Brown-out Reset (BOR) Detection Enable bit (BOR is disabled)
#pragma config ALTI2C1 = OFF            // Alternate I2C pins for I2C1 (SDA1/SCK1 pins are selected as the I/O pins for I2C1)

// FICD
#pragma config ICS = PGD3               // ICD Communication Channel Select bits (Communicate on PGEC3 and PGED3)
#pragma config RSTPRI = PF              // Reset Target Vector Select bit (Device will obtain reset instruction from Primary flash)
#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF             // JTAG Enable bit (JTAG is disabled)

// FAS
#pragma config AWRP = OFF               // Auxiliary Segment Write-protect bit (Aux Flash may be written)
#pragma config APL = OFF                // Auxiliary Segment Code-protect bit (Aux Flash Code protect is disabled)
#pragma config APLK = OFF               // Auxiliary Segment Key bits (Aux Flash Write Protection and Code Protection is Disabled)

#include <xc.h>

/* Setup the clock to run at about 60 MIPS (60,000,000Hz) */
#define FXTL   (10000000L)  /* External crystal frequency */
#define PLL_N1 (2L)         /* PLLPRE  CLKDIV<4:0> range 2 to 33 */
#define PLL_M  (48L)        /* PLLDIV  PLLFBD<8:0> range 2 to 513 */
#define PLL_N2 (2L)         /* PLLPOST CLKDIV<7:6> range 2, 4 or 8 */
#define FSYS (FXTL*PLL_M/(PLL_N1*PLL_N2))
#define FCYC (FSYS/2L)
/* 
 * Warning non-portable function
 * 
 * This function waits for the at least the 
 * specified number milliseconds then returns.
 */
void delay( unsigned int wait_ms )
{
    register unsigned int temp = wait_ms;
    if(temp) do
    {
        asm("    repeat  %0 \n" 
            "    clrwdt     \n"
            "    repeat  %0 \n" 
            "    clrwdt     \n"
            "    repeat  %0 \n" 
            "    clrwdt     \n"
            "    repeat  %0 \n" 
            "    clrwdt     \n"
            : /* no outputs */ 
            : "r" (FCYC/4/1000-3)
            ); 
    } while(--temp);
}
/*
 * Initialize this PIC
 */
void Init_PIC(void)
{
    uint16_t ClockSwitchTimeout;
    /*
     * Disable all interrupt sources
     */
       __builtin_disi(0x3FFF); /* disable interrupts for 16383 cycles */
    IEC0 = 0;
    IEC1 = 0;
    IEC2 = 0;
    IEC3 = 0;
    IEC4 = 0;
    IEC5 = 0;
    IEC6 = 0;
    IEC7 = 0;
    IEC8 = 0;
    __builtin_disi(0x0000); /* enable interrupts */
    /* 
     * Before changing the oscillator to use the PLL
     * we must switch to a clock source that does not
     * use the PLL.
     */

    /* Check if clock switching is unlocked */
    if(OSCCONbits.CLKLOCK == 0)
    {
        /* Initiate Clock Switch to FRC oscillator (NOSC=0b000) */
        __builtin_write_OSCCONH(0x00);

        /* start clock switch */
        __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | _OSCCON_OSWEN_MASK);

          /* wait for oscillator switch to complete */
        for(ClockSwitchTimeout=60000; (ClockSwitchTimeout != 0) && (OSCCONbits.OSWEN != 0); --ClockSwitchTimeout);


        /* Configure PLL prescaler, PLL postscaler, PLL divisor */
#if   PLL_N2==2
        CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST=0; /* N2=2 */
#elif PLL_N2==4
        CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST=1; /* N2=4 */
#elif PLL_N2==8
        CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST=3; /* N2=8 */
#else
#error invalid PLL_N2 paramenter
#endif
        CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE=PLL_N1-2; /* N1=2 */

        PLLFBD=PLL_M-2;

        /* Initiate Clock Switch to Primary oscillator with PLL (NOSC=0b011) */
        __builtin_write_OSCCONH(0x03);

        /* start clock switch */
        __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | _OSCCON_OSWEN_MASK);

          /* wait for oscillator switch to complete */
        for(ClockSwitchTimeout=60000; (ClockSwitchTimeout != 0) && (OSCCONbits.OSWEN != 0); --ClockSwitchTimeout);

        /* Wait for PLL to lock */
        for(ClockSwitchTimeout=60000; (ClockSwitchTimeout != 0) && (OSCCONbits.LOCK  != 1); --ClockSwitchTimeout);
    }
}
/*
 * Main application
 */
int main(void) 
{
    // output
    TRISDbits.TRISD0 = 0;
    // turn led on before clock switch
    LATDbits.LATD0 = 1;

    Init_PIC();

    for(;;)
    {
        LATDbits.LATD0 ^= 1;
        delay(100);
    }
    return 0;
}
/*
 * Catch oscillator fail trap
 */
void __attribute__ ((interrupt, no_auto_psv)) _OscillatorFail(void)
{
    OSCCONbits.CF = 0;
    while(1);
}
```